# angular acces Virtual Directories in IIS with port 4200

Tags: angular, iis, virtual-directory

i have configured an IIS virual directory that have some photos, but i have trublle accessing from an anglar App. i have a 404 NOT FOUND error. at the same i can access the folder from a link with an 80 port.

i tried to add port 4200 on binding on IIS, but the application wont work in that case

i have added this code startup but even if delete it it has no impact:

```
public override void AddApplicationSpecificConfigure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        {

            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "UploadedImages")),
            RequestPath = "/StaticFiles",
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
        });
```

this is how i recieve the link of the image:
[image: recueved url]

HTML call:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="url">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Image Url </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img [src]="element.url" /> </td>
 </ng-container>
```

i can acces photos from this link: [image: link works]

this the error:
[image: error]

IIS binding on port 80[image]

Comment: "i tried to add port 4200 on binding on IIS, but the application wont work in that case" Show IIS site bindings after you add port 4200.

Comment: I remembered the default port number of angular is 4200. Please try to modify the default port in json file to 80. Or you may need to check whether 4200 port has been enabled on your server firewall . Otherise, change binding to 4200 should work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have created virtual directory in Default Web Site running on 80 port. Check your port binding in IIS manager for application.

[image]

Comment: yes it is running on port 80 but when i add the port 4200 i cant run my app anymore